# Find out all GIT changes in a certain line in a file

Tags: git

I have a line of code that was changed recently into a non-working state.

How can I find out who and in which commit changed this particular line?

I tried

```
git log -some_distinct_string_from_that_line --pretty=format:'%h %an -- %s -- %ad'
```

Which shows all commits with comments and authors that changed anything where a line contained "one_distinct_string_from_that_line", but how can I see the actual changes they made?

EDIT:
I also installed `git-gui` and looked at the line with `git gui blame filename` but there is only one commit change for that line shown, although there definitely have been more changes.

I checked with the graphical gui smartgit to look through all changes made on that file by hand and I found 3 commits, where that line was definitely edited (a `#` was first removed and then in another commit added again)

Is there another way that doesn't relay on the git blame functionality, and doesn't relay on the assumption, that the line is in the commit-diff?

Comment: Why do you exclude `git blame`? What do you mean with "`[...] doesn't relay on the assumption, that the line is in the commit-diff`"? Every line has to occure in the diff.

Comment: The only way I could find was with the graphical gui smartgit so far, which shows me, that **there was one more change** in that file a few months ago, that just deleted the `#` at the start of that line. But none of the other methods (using blame) shows me that specific commit. I thought maybe another approach would let me find out the change. Maybe we found a bug here?

Comment: Probably not. Git blame is just fine finding out which commit introduced/modified a line. Git `blame` will print the commit ID. The manual approach is to locate that line at `HEAD`, look for the commit ID and do another `blame` with the predecessor of that revision e.g. `git blame 0deadbee~1 -- <FILE>`. Repeat this step. If you can't find that line anymore in `<REV>~1`, `<REV>` probably was the introducing commit. Git show can help identifying how a line looked prior a removal or modification. It's hard to do these steps programatically since no program/script understands the code you inspect.

Comment: But why does smartgit find that commit and git blame not?

Answer (score 7):

`git blame`. The -L option takes a range of lines and you can select a file as for git log. So `git blame -L 10,20 -- my/file.txt` will show the most recent git commit that touched each of the lines in that file. `git gui blame my/file.txt` does the same job but with a UI to let you browse back in time.

Comment: This is actually much better than my answer. `git gui blame yourfile.txt` then go to the line in question. You can click on the commit SHA1 on the left to move in time and see the successive changes to those lines.

Comment: How do you get `git gui`?

Comment: It is included in the git source distribution and with Git for Windows. On Debian based Linux you would add the git-gui package and I'm sure similar packages exist for most distributions. It is often separated out from command-line git due to the extra dependencies on UI packages (Tcl/Tk, X, and so on).

Comment: I installed `apt-get install git-gui` and looked at the line with `git blame file` but there is only one commit change for that line shown, although there have definitely been more changes.

Comment: `git blame` and `git gui blame` both show the *most* *recent* commit to touch each line. In the GUI you click on the commit link and it re-generates the display using that commit as the new reference and will now show the previous commit that affected that line. The back arrow at the top then lets you got forwards in time again if necessary.

Answer (score 5):

You can add the following line into your `.git/config` file in the `[alias]` section:

`findchange = !sh -c \"git log --pretty=format:'COMMIT %C(yellow)%h %an -- %s -- %ad%C(reset)' -G'$1' -p --word-diff-regex='[A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9]|$1' --color=always ${@:2} | egrep '$1|^COMMIT|-{3} a\\/|\\+{3} b\\/' \"`

Then, just execute the following command at the command line:

```
git findchange 'yourText'
```

Explanation:

- I modified your pretty format slightly so that you will be able to spot the beginning of each commit.
- Using the `-p` options for log, which displays a patch, hence the p, for each commit.
- Using the `--word-diff-regex` option to define a word. This will display changes inline grouped by whole words or single non-word characters.

  - Included the search text itself as part of the regex; otherwise, it does not catch cases where the change spans words
- `--color=always` preserves the coloring even when piping to `egrep`.
- `egrep` finds all lines that are one of the following:

  - the commit message
  - the text you are searching for (either deleted or added)
  - the original name of the changed file
  - the new name of the changed file

Comment: thanks for the fine enhancement, but still, this doesn't seem to find all changes on that line

Comment: @rubo77 Can you give me an example?

Comment: No. I get `-: Bad substitution`

Comment: @rubo77 Try substituting sh for /bin/bash or /bin/ksh. It works with sh on my system, but different types of shells work in different ways.

Comment: The final dash (`-`) does not seam to be necessary. (It did not cause me problems, but maybe that is your issue.) I included it because I have seen many places that say that it is necessary, but I have tried it without the final dash, and it does not seem to be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

using `gitk`, you could do something like that :

```
gitk -Sone_distinct_string_from_that_line -- /some_sub_dir/containing/the/file
```

You will get a partial history containing only the commits where `one_distinct_string_from_that_line` was in the diff.
For each commit, you can see the author, the comments, the context, and check what changed exactly.

The part after `--` is optionnal, it restricts the research to a subdir of your repository.

Comment: this looks fine, it is a gui for what I see on the console with just git -S, but there is only the very first commit included. the last commit, I just made is missing there too

Comment: Hum.. then you have something wrong on your end =). But check out @patthoyts answer

Comment: Alternatively you could add `--all` to the options of `gitk`. Are you sure your last commit is on the same branch ?

Comment: definitely on the same branch (trunk) I have some more edits in that line. Maybe the problem is, that there was just a commenting `#` removed and added in the other commits?

Comment: Git doesn't know anything about comments or language features. And as far as I know, git deals with changes (and content really) on a line by line basis. that is, if you change one character on a line that contains the string `whatever`, the whole line is added in the diff. Therefore `gitk -Swhatever` should pick it up.

Comment: I know, but in this case it definitely doesn't. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

execute below command

```
cd repo<Project>
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

change some line of code

than compare with branch,tag etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pycharm's git integration, you can select the lines of interest and use git-show history for selection from the context menu