# How to see changed lines with certain words and the containing file for a git commit? - Can git diff print a file name line prefix?

Tags: git, bash, awk, grep, git-diff

Before pushing a Git commit, I usually want to review all TODOs that I've added in the code. I've tried several approaches, but I'm still haven't found a good way to do this.

E.g. with the following command, I can see all TODOs added (and removed) in the last commit:

```
git diff HEAD^ | grep "TODO"
```

However in this output I don't see which files contained the change so I have to guess or search the corresponding files. With the following command, I see all files with a "TODO" change, but I don't see the actual TODOs:

```
git diff HEAD^ --name-only -G "TODO"
```

So my question is how can I both see the diff line and the name of the file containing the difference? Is it e.g. possible to make `git diff` prefix every diff line with the file name? Then the grep'ed lines would give have all the information I need.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443412/find-out-all-git-changes-in-a-certain-line-in-a-file/27475802#27475802) to a similar question.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24456418/2541573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is getting close to what I originally wanted:

```
git diff HEAD^ --name-only -G "TODO" | xargs git grep "TODO" --
```

This prints all TODOs in the files touched in the last commit - and not just the TODOs that were added.

But this is also quite useful. In this way I can also check if there may be other TODOs that can now be removed.